# Why is the libvo-aacenc / libvo_aacenc not found?

Tags: libav, aac, configure

When using this https://libav.org/releases/libav-12.3.tar.gz library and running in the folder: "./configure --enable-static --enable-version3 --enable-libvo-aacenc" the error "ERROR libvo_aacenc not found" shows up. If I run "./configure --enable-static --enable-libvo-aacenc" the message libvo-aacenc is version3 and version3 is not specified. "./configure --list-encoders" shows aac as well as libvo-aacenc.

Why can't I activate the libvo-aacenc?

Comment: Did you compile and install libvo-aacenc?

Comment: Yes, locally. with ./configure + flaks and then make install. The other libraries in the libavutil, libavformat, libavcodec and so on work fine.